# Write an equation with the lowest degree , one of whose roots are $\sqrt{3}-i\cdot \sqrt{2}$, with integral coefficients

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

I know that with the conjugate root theorem, the conjugate is also a root. However, the integral coefficients part trips me up, as my polynomial has a irrational coefficient.

Comment: Which quadratic had you got?

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Rational_Root_Theorem

Comment: Just for fun, this would be one heavy-handed solution: [`resultant[ x^2 - 3, (z-x)^2 + 2, x ] = z^4 - 2 z^2 + 25`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%5B+x%5E2+-+3,+(z-x)%5E2+%2B+2,+x+%5D).

Comment: @dxiv [`MinimalPolynomial[Sqrt[3]-I*Sqrt[2]]`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MinimalPolynomial%5BSqrt%5B3%5D-I*Sqrt%5B2%5D%5D) gives the same result.

Comment: @user202729 Right, but that's overly cheating ;-) With the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) you still have to do some thinking beforehands.

Answer (score 3):

$$ x = \sqrt 3 + i \sqrt 2$$
$$ \iff x - (\sqrt 3 + i \sqrt 2) = 0$$
$$ \Rightarrow (x - \sqrt 3 + i \sqrt 2)\times (x - \sqrt 3 - i \sqrt 2) = 0$$
$$ \iff (x - \sqrt 3 + i \sqrt 2)\times (x - \sqrt 3 - i \sqrt 2) = 0$$
$$ \iff (x - \sqrt 3)^2 - (i \sqrt 2)^2 = 0$$
$$ \iff (x - \sqrt 3)^2 - (i \sqrt 2)^2 = 0$$
$$ \iff x^2 - 2 \sqrt 3 x + 5 = 0 $$
That's probably what you had got. Some of its coefficients are still irrational, we should continue, using similar approach.
$$ \Rightarrow (x^2 - 2 \sqrt 3 x + 5)\times (x^2 + 2 \sqrt 3 x + 5) = 0 $$
$$ \Rightarrow (x^2 + 5) ^2 - (2 \sqrt 3 x) ^2 = 0 $$

Answer (score 1):

So using your idea, 
$$  P(x) = \left( x - \left(\sqrt{3} + \mathrm{i}\sqrt{2} \right) \right) \left( x - \left(\sqrt{3} - \mathrm{i}\sqrt{2} \right) \right) = x^2 - 2\sqrt{3} x + 5  \text{.}  $$
What does this tell us?  If you already have $\sqrt{3}$ as a legal coefficient, then you have got the identified root using a degree two (or degree one, since we haven't verified that we actually *need* a quadratic) polynomial.  However, $\sqrt{3}$ is not a legal coefficient since it is not an integer.  How do we clear that up?  We want the roots of 
$$  x^2 - 2 \sqrt{3} x + 5 = 0  $$
so
$$  x^2 + 5 = 2 \sqrt{3} x  \text{,}  $$
giving 
$$  x^4 + 10 x^2 + 25 = (x^2 + 5)^2 = (2 \sqrt{3} x)^2 = 12 x^2  \text{.}  $$  Then our polynomial is 
$$ x^4 -2 x^2 + 25  \text{,}  $$ it has the specified root, and it has integer coefficients.

How do we verify that a lower degree polynomial would not suffice?  Let $z = \sqrt{3} - \mathrm{i}\sqrt{2}$.  Construct a table of powers.  We only need to go up to $z^3$ since we already know a degree four solution to our problem.
\begin{align*}
z^0 &= 1  \\
z^1 &= \sqrt{3} - \mathrm{i}\sqrt{2}  \\
z^2 &= 1 - \mathrm{i} 2 \sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}  \\
z^3 &= -3 \sqrt{3} - \mathrm{i} 7 \sqrt{2}
\end{align*}
If we can find integer combinations (not all zero) of the powers less than $k$ (for $k=0,1,\dots$) that sum to zero, then we have found a lower degree polynomial that has the required root.

- Clearly, the only integer multiple of $z^0$ giving zero is $0 \cdot z^0$, which is not "not all zero".
- Of $z^0$ and $z^1$, the only integer multiple of $z^1$ with no imaginary part is $0$, so there is no polynomial if degree one.
- Of $z^0$, $z^1$, and $z^2$, if the coefficient of $z^1$ is nonzero, then the real part of the sum has a nonzero multiple $\sqrt{3}$, which is not an integer.  This would prevent the sum being zero.  Therefore, the coefficient of $z^1$ is zero, leaving no way to eliminate the imaginary part of $z^2$ unless its coefficient is also zero.  So there is no polynomial of degree two having the specified root.
- Of $z^0, \dots, z^3$, we must have $3$-times as many $z^1$ as $z^3$ to cancel the $\sqrt{3}$ in the real part.  But this produces an imaginary part that is an integer multiple of $10 \sqrt{2}$, which cannot be cancelled by any integer multiple of $z^2$ or $z^0$.  So there is no polynomial of degree three having the specified root.

Consequently, the lowest degree polynomial having $z$ as a root has degree four and we have already found such a polynomial.